# Update Error - same values of primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

I need to update table looking like this:

[image]

Primary key is composite - `id_planu` and `por_cislo`.

When adding new row e.g. `id_planu = '8' AND por_cislo = '5'`, I need to increment all the rows having `por_cislo > 5` like `por_cislo  = por_cislo+1`

There is an issue because when I do that:

```
UPDATE table SET por_cislo = por_cislo+1 WHERE id_planu = '8' AND por_cislo > '5'
```

there is set value of `por_cislo = '7'` where it was `'6'`. So there are two rows with same value of primary key (`8,7`) that is the reason of the error I receive.

How should I do that the correct way?

Comment: Modifying a primary key doesn't sound like a good idea. You don't want to be re-using a key for another record and bumping everything to accommodate. Just generate a new record with a new key, don't re-use old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to add `ORDER BY` clause like following:
`UPDATE table SET por_cislo = por_cislo+1 WHERE id_planu = '8' AND por_cislo > '5' ORDER BY por_cislo DESC`